# switching curve 3d to 2d getting flat

Tags: bezier-curves

Watching this reference [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4FOCC357Hs) @ 2.50

After creating the profile shape. When he switch from 3d to 2d the face get fill. I created a simple triangle shape and trying to switch from 3d to 2d why my curve get flat and not get fill.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion whats going wrong or why i cant fill the face switching to 2d. Thanks

Comment: Is it filled already? If you show screen information it will show you the face and vertex count.  Blender has many options in the 3D View to show such information

Comment: If you draw a very curvy shape such a the text [S] converted to a curve, then the results may be extremely obvious

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger no there are no faces seen https://imgur.com/a/urnf1ym

Comment: 2D curves assume the curve's object-Z is normal to the plane of the control-points. In Object mode, rotate the triangle so it lies in XY, and then apply the rotation. If still no fill, kick it. Set the fill to 'None', and back again to one of the other settings.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: Rotate on X 90 degrees and apply rotation. 2D is truncating the Z axis.

Comment: The scale already applied.Plz check the blend file attach

Comment: Your .blend file is what I am referring to. The SIZE of the triangle is tiny. Try my answer:
Scale up 1000 times, apply scale (again) and try to make 2D. It worked in your .blend file.

Comment: not working here https://imgur.com/a/Hno2aAv

Comment: Weird, this is how your file opens for me, note the dimensions https://ibb.co/FsQHSfg

Comment: Sorry mate... See corrected answer.

Comment: First thing I did was rotate, then hit 2D, didn't work. Then scaled and by habit did apply rotation and scale, thought it was the scale that did the trick :P